# How can I order NULL values first on a Doctrine 2 collection using annotations?

Tags: php, symfony, sorting, doctrine-orm

I have a project using Symfony 2 and containing Doctrine 2 entities. Some of these entities are related to each other. This association is defined by an annotation:

```
/**
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Event", mappedBy="firstEntityId" cascade={"persist", "remove"})
 * @ORM\OrderBy({"dateEnd" = "DESC", "dateBegin" = "DESC"})
*/
private $events;
```

As you can see, this association contains several events that have a start and an end date. When retrieving this collection, I want to have the most recents events (i.e. those which have not ended yet or have ended recently) sorted first.

The problem with the current approach is that it will sort events with an end date of `NULL` after all other events.

How can I tell Doctrine to sort the events with an end date of `NULL` first and then sort the remaining events by descending end date?

I have so far seen several questions on SO about how to tell Doctrine how to order entities. However, none of them mention annotations. Tricks with reversing the sign as suggested e.g. in [Doctrine 2 Order By ASC and Null values in last](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23420522/doctrine-2-order-by-asc-and-null-values-in-last) do not work because Doctrine does not accept anything other than a property name and `ASC` or `DESC` in the annotation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Probably not.** There is an SQL syntax that allows to `ORDER BY column DESC NULLS FIRST`. However, it is not supported by all DB vendors and thus if I scanned the merge request correctly, has not been [merged into DQL](https://github.com/doctrine/doctrine2/pull/100). Depending on which database platform you use, you may be lucky. The comments in the merge request provide insight into how to extend Doctrine at different points to implement the behavior, maybe that helps you to do it by yourself.

Comment: Thanks. I have seen this as well and tried to use it, but the problem is that the code explicitly checks for `ASC` and `DESC` and does not allow any other string. http://www.doctrine-project.org/api/orm/2.1/source-class-Doctrine.ORM.Persisters.BasicEntityPersister.html#889

Answer (score 25):

It's an old post but i found a pretty simple solution if you are using doctrine query builder :

```
$sortDirection = 'ASC';
$qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('e');
$qb->addSelect('CASE WHEN e.valueToOrder IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS HIDDEN myValueIsNull');

//other stuffs
//$qb->where ...

$qb->orderBy('myValueIsNull','ASC');
$qb->addOrderBy('e.valueToOrder',':sortDirection');
$qb->setParameter(':sortDirection',$sortDirection);

return $qb->getQuery()->getResult();
```

PHP way, besides being slower, avoid to use offsets (for an infinite scroll for example)

Thanks to https://stackoverflow.com/a/23420682/6376420

Comment: If you want null values first use  `$qb->orderBy('myValueIsNull','DESC');`

Answer (score 1):

My workaround is to create add an additional select to the query and extract the entity from the resulting array collection, it would be better to have it only examined in query time and not select it (to keep the result array intact) but I have not found a proper solution to this yet (using `QueryBuilder`).

```
$queryBuilder = $this->getEntityManager()->createQueryBuilder();
$queryBuilder->select('e')
    ->from(Entity::class, 'e')
    // We use ZZZZ here as placeholder to push the null values last, use 'AAAA' to sort them first.
    ->addSelect('CASE WHEN(e.name IS NULL) THEN \'ZZZZ\' ELSE e.name END AS name')
    ->addOrderBy('name', 'ASC');

    // As we have a array result due to the "addSelect()" above, we must extract the entities now, in this example by looping over the result array.
    $entities = array_map(function ($contributor) {
        return $contributor[0];
    }, $queryBuilder->getQuery()->getResult());
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and this was my approach:

If we are not talking about a huge amount of processing you can use a custom sort, I needed to have the results sorted by a column in asc or desc depending on user choice. BUT, I also needed the null values of the same column to appear first. So after a lot of googling for the NULLS FIRST approach I decided to make an usort right after you get the result from the query builder:

```
    // Custom sort to put the nulls first
    usort($invoices, function(Entity $a, Entity $b) use ($order) {
        if(null === $a->getNumber())
            return -1;
        if(null === $b->getNumber())
            return 1;

        if(strtoupper($order) == "DESC") {
            if($a->getNumber() > $b->getNumber())
                return -1;
            if($b->getNumber() > $a->getNumber())
                return 1;
        } else {
            if($a->getNumber() < $b->getNumber())
                return -1;
            if($b->getNumber() < $a->getNumber())
                return 1;
        }
    });
```

This way when you get the results from the QueryBuilder you will get the NULLS first and then you will have your original sorting. if it was ASC it will stay ASC and vice-versa.

In case NULL values are required at the end you just need to change the first 'if' to the contrary sign.

I know this question is already Answered but thought I might leave this here in case it helps someone else.

Answer (score 0):

add (-) before the field check the exmaple i have make distance negative then the nulls values will be last . u will get negative distance value use obs() function to remove the (-) from your result .

```
 $repository = $em->getRepository('App\Auth\Entity\User');
      $query = $repository->createQueryBuilder('u')
        ->addSelect('u.id,u.fname,u.lname, - (u.filed_one + :param1) as  distance')
        ->orderBy('distance',"desc")
        ->setParameter('param1', $param1)
        ->getQuery();
```